# Switching from different sources using a microprocessor

Tags: switches

What I want to be able to do is have a way to switch between different 3.7 volt lithium batteries to charge them and monitor them and be able to have them connected in series through switching as well. I want to be able to control all of this through a microprocessor.

What type of switch could be used for this?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you clarify your question and tell us what kind of charger you are using to charge the batteries and something about the microprocessor that you intend to use.

Comment: Are you powering the microprocessor from the batteries you're switching? If so, there are dedicated ICs that can do power source switching without interruption (meaning that you don't lose power in between sources)

Answer (score 1):

A [relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay) will do it. Though it may be more proper to describe it as a [relay module](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/5v-relay-module), because you can not use a relay alone and switch it with a microcontroller.

Be careful switching from parallel to series, if the timing and/or design is wrong you'll short out a battery.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider ICs out there that will help you handle Li-Ion batteries, including charging, power-path switching, discharge control and DC-DC conversion (say, for stepping up that voltage); you can talk to the ICs and batteries through I2C and they make the job way easy.

An example would be the Linear Tech LTC1760 for a system using a pair of smart Li-Ion battery packs.